# Weird behavior of custom function with pandas aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume this data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'user_id'         : [1,  1,    2,  2, 1, 3,   1 ],
     'purchase_id'     : [3,  2,    3,  1, 1, 2,   3 ],
     'purchase_amount' : [10, 0.50, 10, 1, 1, 0.50,10]}
)
```

I have a custom function I want to apply, and it works:

```py
def m(x):

    len(x)
    x = np.mean(x ** 2)
    return(x)

print(df['purchase_amount'].aggregate(m))
#> 43.214285714285715
```

However, when I remove the (seemingly irrelevant) `len()` statement, the code fails:

```py
def m(x):

    # len(x) 
    x = np.mean(x ** 2)
    return(x)

print(df['purchase_amount'].aggregate(m))
#> 0    10.0
#> 1     0.5
#> 2    10.0
#> 3     1.0
#> 4     1.0
#> 5     0.5
#> 6    10.0
#> Name: purchase_amount, dtype: float64
```

If I replace `# len(x)` with some non-comment (e.g. `1`), it also gives the same unexpected result.

To me this is really unexpected. What am I missing? I run pandas 0.24.1 on Windows.

Comment: I can confirm that I have tested the script and it has weird result.

Comment: The second result is applying `np.mean(x**2)` on each row and not over the column. Its weird indeed.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: To get your desired output you can simply do `print(np.mean(df['purchase_amount'] ** 2))`

---

[`Series.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.aggregate.html) docs say:

> func : function, str, list or dict Function to use for aggregating the
>   data. If a function, must either work when passed a Series **or when
>   passed to Series.apply**.

When you have `len(x)` it raises an exception when `m` is called for the first time (because `x` is a float and float objects do not have `len`). This exception causes pandas to fallback and call `m` again, this time passing it to `apply` (as documented).

If we investigate `Series.aggregate` source we can see this behavior:

```
...
result = None
if axis == 0:
    try:
        result, how = self._aggregate(func, axis=0, *args, **kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        pass
if result is None:
    return self.apply(func, axis=axis, args=args, **kwargs)
return result
```

Comment: Thanks. But `m` works on the Series, i.e. `m(pd.Series([1, 2, 3]))` gives the expected output, so why does it fallback to `Series.apply`? Or asked the other way round: Why is `x` a float here and not a Series?

Comment: @LorenzWalthert If you add `print(type(x), x)` you will see that `m` is being called several times, each time with a single element of the series.

Comment: It's still unclear to me. So when I aggregate, I don't want to transform each value separately, but calculate a scalar summary statistic. So I tried to use `pd.Series.apply`, which is what you say my desired solution dispatches to, but I could not make it work. How would your solution look like if you wanted to achieve what I got with the uggly `len()` statement in the code?

Comment: @LorenzWalthert `print(np.mean(df['purchase_amount'] ** 2))` ?

Comment: Agree for that one case, but the idea was initially to have a lot of summary functions, so I could reduce duplication when passing a list / dict / tuple of functions to`pd.DataFrame.aggr()`. But I guess instead of the misleading `len()`, I could also simply assert that the input is a Series within `m()`.